# QNetworkAccessManager :why does reply.rawHeaderPairs () ==[] here?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I am absolutely a newbie to QtNetwork module ，here is a simple question.
why does reply.rawHeaderPairs () ==[] here ?
is there something wrong ?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork  import *


if __name__ == '__main__':


    app =QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    manager=QNetworkAccessManager ()
    url =input('input url :')

    print(QUrl.fromEncoded(QUrl(url).toEncoded()))
    request=QNetworkRequest (QUrl.fromEncoded(QUrl(url).toEncoded()))


    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent" ,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1')
    reply = manager.get(request)

    print(reply.rawHeaderPairs () )
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `get` request hasn't actually finished. So there is no header data to actually look at.

`QNetworkReply::get()` is not a blocking function call. The `QNetworkReply` object returned by `manager.get()` will let you know when the `get` request has actually finished via the various [signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#signals) that it emits.